# Android webview not displaying content correctly

Tags: java, android, webview, html

Im displaying content from a webpage inside my app using a webview, my problem is that the content is not being displayed correctly in all devices.

This is how it should look, and how it looks in a device running in 5.1.1 (Lollipop):

[image]

And this is how it look in a device running on 4.4.2 (KitKat), its also how it looks on device running in 4.1 - 4.3 (Jellybean):

[image]

And here is the code im using to display the webpage:

```
 rootview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_browser, container, false);
            final WebView viewer = (WebView) rootview.findViewById(R.id.webview);

            WebSettings webSettings = viewer.getSettings();
            webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            viewer.getSettings().setLayoutAlgorithm(WebSettings.LayoutAlgorithm.SINGLE_COLUMN);
            viewer.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
            viewer.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
            url="https://exampleURL.com";
            viewer.loadUrl(url);
return rootview;
```

Any idea on how can I fix or why is it happening?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: could be of the difference in HTML5 support? Unless you post the full HTML+CSS+JS here there's no way we can know